# packaging libraries in c++

Tags: c++

I am a java developer for last four years . I am planning to develop an c++ application which uses the library like boost etc.
In java we can add the libraries in class path and export as single jar and distribute it .
I am not sure how to do this in c++ and more over i use ant for build too in java.

Do we have any build too like ant for c++.

What are the things we need to consider while developing an c++ application in terms for supporting different operating systems and some general things.

Do c++ have some thing like maven in java?

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing like Maven for C++. Dependency Management is usually done either by your operating system (Unix package manager like apt-get or yum) or by Hand (Windows ;)).

For multi platform environments I would recommend CMake as it can generate Project files for Visual Studio, Eclipse, XCode, Unix Makefiles etc. CMake can provide you with a lot of tool functions like find_package (XXXXX) which make life a lot easier.

IMHO the best way to learn it is to read documentation of your compiler, your build tool (e.g. CMake) and some sample code. Some keywords are 'static library', 'dynamic library' (like DLLs, 'linking'), include path. Start with something simple like a small program which uses Boost and maybe the CURL library and try to build it on multiple platforms.

Comment: Nope, its too long ago. But the web is full with CMake tutorials.

And: Ignore anything about autoconf, automake & friends, that's all last century. (IMHO) Rather write pure Makefiles.